# Sending Fetch Request from Client to Server results in 404 Next.js Express

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

Im trying to figure out some routing issues with express, im using next.js as well but i dont think that is the issues.

Originally, i have my clientside POST request pointing to `/server`, the same with my server.js, which works out fine. If i switch it to `/api/submit` on both client and server, this results in a 404 error. I'm sure there is a misconfiguration with my routing in express but i cant seem to figure it out. below is my code:

clientside:

```
const submitFormData = e => {
e.preventDefault();
const { formDataOne, formDataTwo } = props;
const formData = {
  formDataOne,
  formDataTwo,
};
fetch('/api/submit', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    data: formData,
  }),
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    server.use(bodyParser.json());

    server.post('/api/submit', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body);
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(3000, err => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a leading `/` in your route path:

```
server.post('/api/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: whoops sorry, that's been fixed. but it still results in a 404 error.